# How to assign <List<Data>> to list variable?

Tags: dart, flutter

How to display one by one data using this DB function?

```
Future<List<Data>> display() async {
    //final Database db = await database;
    var db = await db1;
    final List<Map<String, dynamic>> maps = await db.query('syncTable');

    return List.generate(maps.length, (i) {
      return Data(
        syn_TableName: maps[i]['syn_TableName'],
        syn_ChangeSequence: maps[i]['syn_ChangeSequence'],
      );
    });
  }
```

Comment: Do you just want to Display the `Data` as a `Text` or what is your intention?

Comment: I need to assign to a variable and get one by one values from that variable

Comment: You'll want to use the [FutureBuilder](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html) with your `display()` method. I can give you a detailed answer in 1.5h :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [FutureBuilder](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html) to consume your `display()` method. Then inside the `FutureBuilder` you can use `AsyncSnapshot.data` to get your `List` of `Data`elements.

In the next step you use can call `List.map()` to map your `Data` to widgets. In this example I use the `ListTile` to display:

```
snapshot.data.map((data) {
  return ListTile(
    title: Text(data.syn_TableName),
    subtitle: Text(data.syn_ChangeSequence),
  );
}).toList(),
```

*Here a minimal working example which you can try out:*

[image: Demo]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: FutureBuilder<List<Data>>(
            initialData: [],
            future: display(),
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              return ListView(
                children: snapshot.data.map((data) {
                  return ListTile(
                    title: Text(data.syn_TableName),
                    subtitle: Text(data.syn_ChangeSequence),
                  );
                }).toList(),
              );
            }),
      ),
    );
  }

  Future<List<Data>> display() async {
    return List.generate(15, (i) {
      return Data(
        syn_TableName: 'syn_TableName $i',
        syn_ChangeSequence: 'syn_ChangeSequence $i',
      );
    });
  }
}

class Data {
  final String syn_TableName;
  final String syn_ChangeSequence;

  Data({this.syn_ChangeSequence, this.syn_TableName});
}
```